# Create new columns for the duplicate records:Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have an input **file that is being generated at runtime** of this form:
Case 1:

```
ID,Numbers,P_ID,Cores,Count
1,1234567890,A1,200,3
2,1234567890,A2,150,3
3,0123459876,A3,1000,1
```

The generated file can also be of this form:
Case 2:

```
ID,Numbers,P_ID,Cores,Count
1,1234567890,A1,200,3
3,0123459876,A3,1000,1
```

Expected Output:
Case 1:

```
 Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2 P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
 0   123459876     3     A3     1000        1   NaN   None      NaN      NaN
 1  1234567890     1     A1      200        3   2.0     A2    150.0      3.0
```

Case 2:

```
Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2 P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
0   123459876     3     A3     1000        1   NaN   None      NaN      NaN
1  1234567890     1     A1      200        3   Nan   None      Nan      Nan
```

In the input file there may be 0 or 1 or 2 rows(but never more that 2) with the same Number(1234567890). These 2 rows, i'm trying to summarize into 1 single row(as shown in output file).

I would like to convert my input file into the above structure.How can i do this? I'm really new to pandas. Please be so kind as to help me with this. Thanks in advance.

In the Case 2:

The structure of output file must remain the same i.e., column names should be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

- first create new column with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counting `Numbers`
- then reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
- `MultiIndex` in columns is converted to `Index` with list comprehension

---

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['Numbers', 'g']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1] + 1))) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
      Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2 P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
0   123459876   3.0     A3   1000.0      1.0   NaN   None      NaN      NaN
1  1234567890   1.0     A1    200.0      3.0   2.0     A2    150.0      3.0
```

EDIT:

For converting to `int` is possible use custom function, which convert only if no `error` - so columns with `NaN`s are not changed:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(int)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return x

df['g'] = df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['Numbers', 'g']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1] + 1))) for x in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.apply(f).reset_index()
print (df1)
      Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2 P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
0   123459876     3     A3     1000        1   NaN   None      NaN      NaN
1  1234567890     1     A1      200        3   2.0     A2    150.0      3.0
```

EDIT1:

There has to be 1 or 2 rows per group, so use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) is possible:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(int)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return x

df['g'] = df.groupby('Numbers').cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index(['Numbers', 'g']).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = ['_'.join((x[0], str(x[1] + 1))) for x in df1.columns]
cols = ['ID_1','P_ID_1','Cores_1','Count_1','ID_2','P_ID_2','Cores_2','Count_2']
df1 = df1.apply(f).reindex_axis(cols, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df1)
      Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2  P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
0   123459876     3     A3     1000        1   NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
1  1234567890     1     A1      200        3   NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a bunch. Only i noticed that all the integer values are being converted to float. Any alternate way to resolve that rather than explicitly type casting each column name?

Comment: Hmmm, do you need columns without `NaN`s convert to `int`?

Comment: Not exactly, its only the ID columns namely ID_1 and ID_2 that i have an issue with

Comment: Yes, but only column `ID_1` in output can be converted to `int`, becasue if at least one value of `NaN` in column, it is impossible converting (`ID_2`), because `NaN` is always float.

Comment: Also, can u please take the time to explain to me what u did? If its not too much trouble that is?

Comment: No, give me a sec.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again, but my input file can be of this form also:`ID,Numbers,P_ID,Cores,Count
1,1234567890,A1,200,3
2,0123459876,A3,1000,1`

Comment: Yes, i see. But there is not second ID 3 ? What is logic ?

Comment: In such a situation, expected output has to be like this:`Numbers  ID_1 P_ID_1  Cores_1  Count_1  ID_2 P_ID_2  Cores_2  Count_2
0   123459876     3     A3     1000        1   NaN   None      NaN      NaN
1  1234567890     1     A1      200        3   Nan   None      Nan      Nan`

Comment: the logic is that, the input file may or may not have duplicate Numbers with different values. In such a situation, 'column_names'_2 must be present but with empty records. Did u get what i'm trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. Can you add 2, 3 rows to question and add desired output? All values are changed to NaNs? I dont understand.

Comment: Just give me a minute

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that i'm trying to summarize the input table. There might come a situation when there are no duplicate values for Numbers. At such an instant also  the structure of the output file must remain as it is. According to your code the structure of the output file changes. Can u suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Ok, now understand. Need only `reindex_axis`, give me as ec.

Comment: happy to hear that

Comment: Answer ir edited, simply reindex columns by all possible column names - if column is missing, add new `NaN` col.